# EKEventEditViewAction is not returning .saved enum value but it is returning as .cancel swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am adding an event to the calendar, But even I am clicking the cancel button, the event is getting saved

It should return EKEventEditViewAction.saved value after clicking the Done button but it is returning EKEventEditViewAction.cancel

Every time it is returning EKEventEditViewAction.cancel value.

My Code for creating event is

```
do {
        try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)

        let controller = EKEventEditViewController()
        controller.event = event
        controller.eventStore = eventStore
        controller.editViewDelegate = self
        self.present(controller, animated: true)


    }catch let error as NSError {
        let popup = PopupDialog(title: "Message", message: "Unable to add an event, it doesn't have a valid start date or end date.")
        self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)

        print("error: \(error)")
    }
```

and EKEventEditViewDelegate function for dismissing the controller is

```
func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
    print(action)
    print(action.rawValue)
    print(action.hashValue)
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)

    switch action {
    case .saved:
        print("saved")
        let popup = PopupDialog(title: "Message", message: "Event added to calendar.")
        self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case .canceled:
        print("Canceled")
    case .deleted:
        print("deleted")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because I had added this line

```
try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
```

after remove this do try-catch block and above line of code, it is working fine.

It has happened because I am saving the event with the code even though I am using EKEventEditViewController.

So, I removed `try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)` now my code looks like this

```
let controller = EKEventEditViewController()
controller.event = event
controller.eventStore = eventStore
controller.editViewDelegate = self
self.present(controller, animated: true)
```

Thanks.